# Autocomplete Two TextBoxes Simaltaneously in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

I am in need of a push in the right direction. I have a form which has 2 texboxes - one which has the Autocomplete functionality enabled and gets the data from a DataReader (txtBx1), and the other (txtBx2) which I am trying to complete using the value of txtBx1.

So, when I start typing into txtBx1, the autocomplete works as expected, but what I want is for txtBx2 to be populated at the same time with data from second column of the query used to retrieve the data.

For instance, in txtBx1, I am typing in a Module Reference number, so I want the Module Name to be populated in txtBx2 whilst the automplete in txtBx1 is 'taking place' or once it 'completes'. So far what I have is;

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION="
                             + "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxxxxxxx)(PORT=1521)))"
                             + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = TBL)));"
                              + "User Id=username;Password=password;");
            oraCon.Open();


            OracleCommand ocmodref = new OracleCommand(" SELECT module.reference as ModuleRef, module.name as ModuleName FROM TBL_Module module ", oraCon);
          //OracleCommand ocmodname = new OracleCommand(" SELECT module.name as ModuleName FROM TBL_Module module where module.reference = '" + txtBx1.Text + "' ", oraCon);


            OracleDataReader DRModRef = ocmodref.ExecuteReader();
            //OracleDataReader DRModName = ocmodname.ExecuteReader();

            AutoCompleteStringCollection automodreftext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            //AutoCompleteStringCollection automodnametext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            while (DRModRef.Read() )
            {
               
                automodreftext.Add(DRModRef.GetString(0));
                automodreftext.Add(DRModRef.GetString(1));
                //automodnametext.Add(DRModName.GetString(0));
            }
            
            txtBx1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            txtBx1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtBx1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = automodreftext;

            txtBx2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            txtBx2.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            txtBx2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = automodreftext;

            oraCon.Close();
        }
```

I have commented out the bits I tried earlier which didn't work but I have left them in there just in case you spot something I missed. Also, I have tried triggering the TextChanged event for txtBx1 so that when the text changes as the user searches for a Module Reference, this autocompletes txtBx2 with the name, but alas, no joy!

I'd be more than grateful if you could steer me in the right path.

Best Regards,

Comment: You could handle the `txtBx1.Leave` event to check first whether the `txtBx1.AutoCompleteSource` contains the `txtBx1.Text` and update the `txtBx2.AutoCompleteSource` accordingly. `TextChanged` event is not a good place to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To display the matching Name to the selected Ref# and vise-versa Utilize TextChanged events as so:

```
private void txtBx1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    StringCollection customSource = tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource;
    int index = customSource.IndexOf(tb.Text);

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        txtBx2.Text = txtBx2.AutoCompleteCustomSource[index];
    }
    else
    {
        txtBx2.Text = tb.Text;
    }
}

private void txtBx2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    StringCollection customSource = tb.AutoCompleteCustomSource;
    int index = customSource.IndexOf(tb.Text);

    if (index >= 0)
    {
        txtBx1.Text = txtBx1.AutoCompleteCustomSource[index];
    }
    else
    {
        txtBx1.Text = tb.Text;
    }
}
```

just make sure you set `txtBx2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = automodnametext` and apply AutoComplete transform of your desire to the raw string.

The expected behavior would copy the text between the two textboxes whenever typing into only one; and upon selecting/typing a matching string, the other textbox would also show the desired target string (if transformation is applied).

Comment: thank you for your assistance - I have done exactly as you suggested however  txtBx2 is being (simultaneously) auto-populated with the same value as what I am typing in txtBx1 i.e. the Module Ref instead of the Module Name. It's not until I select the suggested Module Ref in txtBx1 that the value of txtBx2 is changed to the corresponding Module Name. Trying to play around with this, but thank you as this was a very good steer.